# Reducing noise in transactional data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, noise

I have a dataset sent to me weekly with data in daily format for 3-4 large retailers. Metrics I can see are number of customers, transaction counts, and total spend in dollars. The sample size is relatively small (1000-5000 unique customers) but there are strong trends I can see in the 4-5 years of data I have. I am trying to get more accurate y/y numbers for predicting quarterly revenue but currently am generally + or - 10% in using spend data alone. What steps can I take to help reduce noise in the dataset and get more accurate results?

Comment: Hard to judge, we would need more information : more accurate compare to what metric, what modelling approach.

Comment: I guess I am ultimately looking for a jumping off point. When aggregated to quarterly values, the trends are very strong, but as stated above, the y/y comparisons have fairly wide margins of error. I am unsure of what approaches to take and what the best modeling approaches would be for a transactional time series dataset.